# PostgresSQL: interval field value out of range

Tags: postgresql

I am new to PostgresSQL where I am running one query where I am looking for activities within last week but it is throwing out of range error

Postgres SQL:

```
select *
from myTable
where order_time > '2018-12-04 18:22:26' - INTERVAL '7 day'
```

Error:

```
IntervalFieldOverflow: ERROR:  interval field value out of range: "2018-12-04 18:22:26"
```

Version: `PostgresSQL 9.6`

I have tried to resolve my issue by searching online but did not get much help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try casting the timestamp literal string:

```
select *
from myTable
where order_time > '2018-12-04 18:22:26'::timestamp - interval '7 day';
```